# how to use jmockit with spring's mockmvc to test controller

Tags: spring, unit-testing, jmockit

I want to use `mockmvc` to test controller which is recommended by Spring. But, I also have to use `jmockit` to mock the dependences.

The problem is that jmockit can't do well with `mockmvc`, whether the `standaloneSetup()` or the `webAppContextSetup()`.

Another mocking tool named Mockito is well done with this problem, but it has a lot limits in mocking dependencies.

So, anybody has the experience or idea, please tell me. Thank you very much.

The example code is as following:

The first is the Mockito with Spring's `MockMvc` to unit test controller. This runs well.

```
public class TestControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private LoginController loginController;

    @Mock
    private LoginService loginService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(loginController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogin() throws Exception {

        when(loginService.login()).thenReturn(false);

        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/login"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("goodbyeworld"))
                .andReturn();
    }
}
```

Secondly, the jmockit is as following. Unfortunately, the `loginController` is null at the setup method. And, if i just invoke the `loginController.xxx()` in the `@Tested` method is fine. I think this shows that `loginController` is instantiated before `@Tested` method but after `@Before` method.

```
public class TestControllerTest2 {
    @Tested
    private LoginController loginController;

    @Injectable
    private LoginService loginService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(loginController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogin() throws Exception {

        new Expectations() {{
            loginService.login(); result = false;
        }};

        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/login"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("goodbyeworld"))
                .andReturn();
    }
}
```

So, how can this problem be solved? jmockit's handful init method? any possible?

Comment: Can you clarify? I don't know what you mean by the standalone/webappcontext setups. An example test class using mockmvc would help.

Comment: @Rogério, it’s amazing that you have noticed my problem. I am so sorry for the long time update. BTW, the jmockit is really powerful.

Comment: It's not quite in the spirit of JMockit, but you could always instantiate the `loginController` yourself in the `@Before` method.

Comment: @dcsohl, It's easy to instantiate the loginController by myself. But, if I do this, then the dependent object can not be injected automatically. This is also trouble me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differently from Mockito's `@InjectMocks`, JMockit's `@Tested` fields get created only *after* the execution of any `@Before` methods. This happens because of the support for mock parameters in test methods, which doesn't exist in Mockito. Arguably, tested fields should be set early, together with mock fields, so this may change in a future version of JMockit.

Anyway, solutions for the problem as it stands today are:

1. Do not use `@Tested`; instead, instantiate and inject the object under test manually in the `@Before` method.
2. Use `@Tested`, but avoid `@Before` methods which depend on tested fields. In the example test, the `MockMvc` object could be created in each test method by calling a `MockMvc mockMvc() { return MockMvcBuilders... }` method.

Comment: Thank you for your solutions. I think the second way satisfies my requirements much better. The Before method actually execute before every Test method in junit, so with the second way, the only difference is the less clean code.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced similar problem recently, and I have found a little bit of graceful solution:

```
@Tested(availableDuringSetup=true)
NotificationController notificationController;

@Injectable
NotificationService notificationService;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void init() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(notificationController).build();
}
```

`boolean availableDuringSetup` attribute for `@Tested` annotation is the solution :)

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is jmockit can't do well with mockmvc

I find that JMockit and Spring's MockMvc do play together well enough. I have successfully used the webAppContextSetup in my case. Here is an example which may not compile even, but could be a useful guide to get you started..

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.put;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import mockit.*;

import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import some.package.Account;
import some.package.Collaborator;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/context/example1.xml", "classpath:/context/example2.xml" })
public class AccountControllerIntegrationTest {
    private static final String PATH_TO_ACCOUNT = "/accounts/some_account";

    private String exampleAccountJson = "{\"account\":\"Sample\",\"active\":true}";

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mocked
    private Account mockAccount;

    @Mocked
    private Collaborator mockCollaborator;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void should_delete_account() throws Exception {
        new Expectations() {{
            mockAccount.getSomethingWhichReallyShouldNotBeExposed(); result = mockCollaborator;
            mockCollaborator.getSomething(); result = "whatever";
        }};
        mockMvc.perform(delete(PATH_TO_ACCOUNT)).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    public void should_add_account() throws Exception {
        new NonStrictExpectations() {{
            mockAccount.getSomethingWhichReallyShouldNotBeExposed(); result = mockCollaborator;
            mockCollaborator.getSomething(); result = "whatever";
        }};
        mockMvc.perform(put(PATH_TO_ACCOUNT).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(exampleAccountJson)).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

Hope it can help you--good luck!

Comment: you are right. Thank you for you remind. It's a good way of Integration test, however, i have to solve the problem of unit test first.

Comment: Yeah, I find that code I shared rather ugly, but I was getting after some code somebody wrote without benefit of TDD, so I satisfied myself with an integration test. Glad Rogerio was able to help you!